# Can We Change the Height of Segmented Control?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Or will it always be 43?

The change height option in Size Inspector is Greyed Out

Comment: Have you tried setting the frame programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if you change it in code, but IB will do its best to enforce certain HIG rules, this being one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You could give a try to MCSegmented control it has a lot of customization. Search on google for it